# Using valgrind to find out how an object is still reachable

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I use valgrind for memory leak detection. There was some code I was expecting to produce a memory leak, but valgrind did not detect it. Now I would like to find out in what way this object might still be reachable (this would be a problem in this case). Can valgrind output those references?

Comment: Add `--show-reachable=yes --leak-resolution=high` to the command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the (not yet released) 3.8.0 SVN version of Valgrind.
You then have the following gdbserver monitor commands:

> ```
>   block_list <loss_record_nr>
>         after a leak search, shows the list of blocks of <loss_record_nr>
>   who_points_at <addr> [<len>]
>         shows places pointing inside <len> (default 1) bytes at <addr>
>         (with len 1, only shows "start pointers" pointing exactly to <addr>,
>          with len > 1, will also show "interior pointers")
> ```